# Using IF to look at multiple fields to return a set value

Tags: ms-access

I have an access database that tracks our internal quality assurance checks for staff. They have 8 items we track them on and each of those items has 4 possible values:
Pass (1)
Non-Pass (2)
FYI (3)
NP&FYI (4).
You can see these 4 set on the left in the column topped by "CPT". [image: screenshot][1].  What I would like to have happen is if ANY of those 8 fields are FYI (ID 3) it sets the FYI checkbox to true. If ANY are Non-Pass (ID 2) It sets the passing checkboxes to false. If ANY of the fields are NP&FYI (ID 4) I want the two checkboxes to be set to non-pass and FYI. The code I am trying is:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
If (Me.Diagnosis And Me.CPT And Me.DOS And Me.UpDownCode And 
    Me.ChargeCorrections And Me.ChurnEsc And Me.Protocol And Me.BillServProv) 
    = 1 Then
    Me.FYI = 0
    Me.QAFail = -1
    End If
If (Me.Diagnosis Or Me.CPT Or Me.DOS Or Me.UpDownCode Or 
    Me.ChargeCorrections Or Me.ChurnEsc Or Me.Protocol Or Me.BillServProv) = 2 
    Then
    Me.QAFail = 0
    End If
If (Me.Diagnosis Or Me.CPT Or Me.DOS Or Me.UpDownCode Or 
    Me.ChargeCorrections Or Me.ChurnEsc Or Me.Protocol Or Me.BillServProv) = 3 
    Then
    Me.FYI = -1
    End If
If (Me.Diagnosis Or Me.CPT Or Me.DOS Or Me.UpDownCode Or 
    Me.ChargeCorrections Or Me.ChurnEsc Or Me.Protocol Or Me.BillServProv) = 4 
    Then
    Me.FYI = -1
    Me.QAFail = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Unfortunately I'm getting inconsistent results. If I set field like CPT to non-pass then the FYI checkbox tics and the QAFail box does not clear. If I set other fields to other values I get all kinds of different results. I'm assuming its because there is confusion between the possible values of the fields being interpreted by the successive If statements. I thought about using CASE, but I couldn't figure out how to set the case value based on 8 different fields. I'm a novice at VBA, can anyone point me in the right direction?

June7's alt code (works)

```
Dim strCodes As String
With Me
strCodes = Nz(.Diagnosis & .CPT & .DOS & .UpDownCode & _
    .ChargeCorrections & .ChurnEsc & .Protocol & .BillServProv, "")
End With
If InStr(strCodes, 2) > 0 Then
    Me.QAFail = 0
ElseIf InStr(strCodes, 3) > 0 Then
    Me.txtFYI = -1
ElseIf InStr(strCodes, 4) > 0 Then
    Me.txtFYI = -1
    Me.QAFail = 0
ElseIf strCodes <> "" Then
    Me.txtFYI = 0
    Me.QAFail = -1
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Image did not embed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `If` condition returns either a True or False (-1 or 0) not the 1, 2, 3, 4 you are testing for. Every `If` block executes so the last one that meets criteria returns result. Use `ElseIf` then only one `End If`. Use a `With Me` block and don't have to repeat the `Me` qualifier. Why does posted code not show line continuation character? Code assumes every field has a value. If any field is Null or empty string, the test for ID 1 will always return False even if other 7 fields have a 1.

```
With Me
If (.Diagnosis = 1 And .CPT = 1 And .DOS = 1 And .UpDownCode = 1 And _
    .ChargeCorrections = 1 And .ChurnEsc = 1 And .Protocol = 1 And .BillServProv = 1) Then
...
ElseIf (...) Then
...
ElseIf (...) Then
...
ElseIf (...) Then
...
End If
End With
```

Use that same syntax for the `ElseIf` expressions using the `Or` operator.

Make sure testing values in order of priority. If ID 3 should have precedence over 2 and 4 then test for 3 first. I would think 2 has precedence but your narrative contradicts.

Consider alternative code:

```
Dim strCodes As String
With Me
strCodes = Nz(.Diagnosis & .CPT & .DOS & .UpDownCode & _
    .ChargeCorrections & .ChurnEsc & .Protocol & .BillServProv, "") 
End With
If InStr(strCodes, 2) > 0 Then
    ...
ElseIf InStr(strCodes, 3) > 0 Then
    ...
ElseIf InStr(strCodes, 4) > 0 Then
    ...
ElseIf strCodes <> "" Then
    ...
End If
```

Comment: The 8 fields are not yes/no fields they are lookup fields based on a table storing the 4 values. The Numbers I listed are the ID values for those entries. I didn't know about the with/end with statement - I'll try that out.

Comment: I know they aren't yes/no fields. I never said they are. The `If` condition returns a True/False based on whether or not the criteria expressions result in true or false. With `And` all 8 expressions must be True for the condition to be True. With `Or` just any one of the 8 expressions must be True for the condition to be True.

Comment: I tried your alternative code and it works, but I'm not sure I understand the last elseif statement. Access wouldn't accept it without a then statement after it and I put that in there. Should I be putting what I want to have happen if all 8 fields = 1? I've put the code I tried above.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the missing `Then` typo. The condition for all 8 fields = 1 is not really needed. Any situation that doesn't meet the first 3 conditions will be tested by the last condition and if the variable is not an empty string, the code in that ElseIf will execute. After the first 3 conditions are tested, what's left must be only value of 1 in each field (assuming users are prevented from inputting any other values than these four). However, neither code makes sure EVERY field has data. Are users allowed to leave a field empty?

Comment: No by default the fields are set to "1" I wanted the "all are 1" code in there in case some one sets a value to non-pass and then sets it back to pass. I wanted the automatic update to happen. The code is working perfectly! I really appreciate it!  Answer marked.

Comment: Well, the last `ElseIf` will take care of the "all are 1". Could even be just `Else`, without the test for empty string.

Comment: Field may be set with default of 1 but are users allowed to delete value and leave the field empty (Null)? If you don't have validation to prevent that, it certainly could happen, even by accident.

Comment: They cant, its a combo box limited to the list so it always has a value. On another issue I have a question for you on the code you suggested. I have that on the After Update Property of the form. it works on the data entry form. However when I try to add a new record using either the Access Macro or the DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec methods it will not let me add a new record. Any thoughts? Do I have it in the wrong property?

Comment: A combobox with limit to list will still allow Null. User just has to delete input with ESC or DELETE or BACKSPACE key. Should use AfterUpdate of each control. Put code in a Sub behind the form then call the sub from each of the 8 controls.

Comment: Thanks June7, its working perfectly. Thanks for the help and the lesson!